# How does Visual Studio Code (VSCode) know environment variables set in ~/.config/fish/config.fish?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, environment-variables

Environment:

- macOS Catalina
- Visual Studio Code
- fish shell

---

I'm using fish as a default shell and almost every environment variable, include `$PATH`, is set within `~/.config/fish/config.fish` (`~/.bash_profile` in bash). When I use Visual Studio Code, it knows environment variables set in `~/.config/fish/config.fish` though its parent process is `/sbin/launchd`, not fish. How does this occur?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Default Shell

This `chsh -s /usr/local/bin/fish` command made Fish Shell your default **login(1)** shell (as mentioned on [Installing Fish shell on MacOS](https://gist.github.com/gagarine/cf3f65f9be6aa0e105b184376f765262) readme). Fish will be used as your default shell for everything unless specified otherwise.

### How does it know `$PATH`

Every time a new Fish Shell instance is launched it looks at `~/.config/fish/config.fish` file for configurations and tweaks; inside you may have `$PATH` variables set and it will be fed into the `$PATH` variable.

### Visual Studio Code

> The shell used defaults to $SHELL on Linux and macOS, PowerShell on
>   Windows 10 and cmd.exe on earlier versions of Windows. These can be
>   overridden manually by setting terminal.integrated.shell.* in user
>   settings. Arguments can be passed to the terminal shell using the
>   terminal.integrated.shellArgs.* user settings [Read more about
>   configuring the shell](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_configuration)

In OSX it is `terminal.integrated.shell.osx` property that calls $SHELL by defualt (null) or user specified shell

### Overview

login(1) --> 
Sets `$SHELL = /usr/local/bin/fish` --> 
Visual Studio Code gets `$SHELL` --> 
Starts a new Fish Shell instance --> 
Fish Shell loads `~/.config/fish/config.fish` -->
set `$PATH` and other configs